# Cannot connect with rdesktop, but can with remmina

Tags: rdesktop, remmina, rdp

I don't understand what can be the reason of an unsuccessful login with rdesktop.
After I run the command:

```
rdesktop -u "user" -p "pwd" ip-address
```

it shows me the screen of my remote Windows PC with the message "user name or password incorrect" message. After I press the button to retry the login I can see the correct pc name already entered in the corresponding text field. I enter the password and it shows me the error message again. But the password is correct.

The version of rdesktop is 1.8.3

When I connect with remmina there is no such a problem. If you cannot explain why it's so, could you please at least recommend an RDP client that works well from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several reasons generalized by 'invalid credentials' reply
it may be Certificate issue, wrong type of authorization etc.
I think that exact reason can be found in the log files.

Meanwhile you may want to try **xfreerdp** app, it is called from command line and will report issues directly in your console, that later may help you in resolving remmina errors too

Sample command will look like

```
xfreerdp +clipboard /size:1500x900 /u:username@example.com /p:passw0rd /v:hostname.example.com
```

**xfreerdp** is a part of freerdp package which is available for many distributions

Comment: There may be a certificate problem as I was asked to trust one when I connected via xfreerdp, but there wasn't any confirmation request when I tried to connect via rdesktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, where with this

```
rdesktop -u 'user' -p 'pass' IP
```

Windows gave me the error message "The user name or password is incorrect", while using

```
xfreerdp /v:IP /u:user '/p:pass'
```

absolutely worked fine.

After hours of debugging in finally found the problem for - at least - my situation: **It seems that `xfreerdp` automatically detects an Active Directory an tries to authenticate the user within the domain - while `rdesktop` only uses a local user!** (The instructions I followed did not mention that the target host is the domain controller and the user is a domain user.)

So explicitly adding the domain to `rdesktop` finally solved my problem:

```
rdesktop -u 'domain\user' -p 'pass' IP
```

Altough this question is very old and this may not the problem of the OP I hope this helps others who find the question through google (like me). Otherwise you will get more detailed debugging outputs with:

```
RDESKTOP_DEBUG=All rdesktop -v ...
xfreerdp /log-level:DEBUG ...
```